# How does this BJT oscillator work step by step?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, oscillator

[image]

Just in case, the collector of Q1 is connected with the base of Q2 (with the point Vo), I'm specially interested on how the Vo2 Output behaves (details will be appreciated).

Also I would like to know if this kind of circuit has an specific name and what's the approach for calculating its pulse frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that a step-by-step description is not a suitable method for describing the working principle of a harmonic oscillator - more than that: It is not possible and/or does not improve the understanding. This applies to all linear/harmonic oscillators.

Hence, it is best and sufficient to show if and how the oscillation criterion (Barkhausen) will be fulfilled. This criterion requires that we have positive feedback (loop gain larger than "1") with a phase shift of 360 deg (0 deg) at ONE SINGLE frequency fo only (the desired oscillation frequency).
Let us see if the criterion is met:

1.) If both nodes labelled "Vo" are connected we have the chance to provide positive feedback if the phase shift caused by the capacitors allows a phase shift of 0 deg. (Both transistor stages are inverting and do not add additional phase shifts).

2.) Both capacitors (C1 and C2) - together with the corresponding resistive parts form a bandpass with a zero deg phase shift between both stages for one single frequency fo. It is, in principle, a C-R-R-C ladder bandpass structure:

3.) C2 realizes - together with the resistive input of Q1 - a highpass function and C1 is responsible for a lowpass function with a higher corner frequency than for the highpass (C1 is smaller than C2).

4.) This lowpass function comes from the fact that with rising frequencies the capacitor C1 causes an increase of negative feedback for the Q1 stage and, thus, a decreasing gain of this stage.

5.) The total gain of the loop (determined by R1 and R5) must be large enough to ensure a loop gain which is larger than unity at f=fo.

Comment: Do you know about any book that could explain this? Because I'm not that advanced on electronics and maybe that's why I can't fully understand your explanation on how this circuit works...

Comment: To understand the working principle of this circuit it is really necessary to understand the general principles behind oscillators with feedback. Are you aware of the oscillation criterion? Do you understand its meaning? Do you know the meaning of the term "loop gain"? Each book and many Internet contributions dealing with harmonic oscillators will help you.

Comment: My recommendation: Try to understand the working principle of the most simple oscillator: Wien bridge oscillator with an opamp.